# Getting random words using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Im making a hangman game and instead of having a set list which contains a dozen or so words, I would like to have thousands(maybe millions) of words to my disposal and have python pick a random word. How can I do this without writing each words manually to a list?

Comment: Try [NLTK words corpus](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html).

Comment: You access a word list of your choosing.  Open the file, read in the words, and there's your word list.  A simple web search will find you a lot of world lists, if there's not one already on your computer (usually for spell check).

Comment: The usual way they teach you to do this in intro classes is to use the [Unix words dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)). This is a simple file that just contains one word per line, in alphabetical order. If you don't care about Windows, or about minimal Linux installs, try `/usr/share/dict/words`, fall back to `/usr/dict/words` if not there. If you have to work everywhere, the list is public domain, and available all over the internet, so you can just, e.g., `requests.get('https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords')`.

Comment: The various versions will give you anywhere from 40K to 100K words. Once you have those in a list, just use `random.choice` on it.

Comment: British National Corpus - .zip has >500MB http://ota.ox.ac.uk/desc/2554

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [package](https://pypi.org/project/RandomWords/0.1.5/):

```
from random_words import RandomWords
rw = RandomWords()
word = rw.random_word()
```

Comment: this package does not work well with python 3 it seems. Circular imports using 3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

You can download a csv file from the internet with a large number of random words in it, and import it to Python via `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

And then, use `random.choice` to pick a random word from this list.